# Main idea or strategy to evaluate some limit $\lim_{s\to0}\zeta^{(k)}(s)$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, reference-request, riemann-zeta

Seems that it is possible to get using Wolfram Alpha online calculator the limit as $s$ tends to zero of the derivative of the Riemann Zeta function $$\lim_{s\to0}\zeta^{(k)}(s).\tag{1}$$

For example write `lim RiemannZeta'''(s), as s-->0` or `lim RiemannZeta''''(s), as s-->0`

> **Question.** Imagine that one need to justify a limit of previous kind, say us $$\lim_{s\to0}\zeta^{(iv)}(s),\tag{2}$$
>   what is the way to get such closed-form in terms of constants? Isn't required the full expression, only is required how to start with the evaluation of this kind of limit, in this example say us $(2)$. **Many thanks.**

I am asking about a sketch to get the limit, for example what formula I need and what calculations will be need. Thus I don't require all details, since I think that it is tedious, and if you known it from the literature please refer it answering this as a reference request.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may be able to use the analytic continuation of the series in order to be able to differentiate and solve the limit that way. This may be totally fruitless, too, though.

Comment: I've calculate the first derivative using the functional equation (that is valid for $0<\Re s<1$) but I think that my strategy is ridiculous. Yours is much better, many thnaks @Clayton

Comment: if you carry out the details, be sure to let us know how it turns out. I'm fairly curious as the zeta function is where my studies are focused. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Formulas for Higher Derivatives of the Zeta Function," by Tom M. Apostol, Math. Comp., Vol. 44, Num 169, January 1985, pp.223-232.  According to the abstract, a closed form formula is given for $\zeta^{(k)}(0)$ is given, along with along with numerical values to 15D for $k=0\dots 18$

I found this by Googling "Higher derivatives of the zeta function," and then looking at the paper on JSTOR.

Comment: Many thanks, perfect.

Answer (score 2):

We may start from finding an integral representation for $\zeta(s)$ in the region $\text{Re}(s)>-1$.
For any $s$ such that $\text{Re}(s)>0$ we have
$$ \zeta(s)=\left(1-\frac{2}{2^s}\right)^{-1}\eta(s)= \frac{2^s}{\Gamma(s)(2^s-2)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}\,dx\tag{1}$$
and by integration by parts
$$ \zeta(s) = \frac{2^s}{\Gamma(s+1)(2^s-2)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\,dx \tag{2} $$
provides an analytic continuation to the wanted region. For instance, by evaluating $(2)$ at $s=0$ we have
$$ \zeta(0) = -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\,dx =-\frac{1}{2} \tag{3}$$
and if we need to find $\zeta^{(k)}(0)$ we just have to apply $\frac{d^k}{ds^k}$ to the RHS of $(2)$, then evaluate at $s=0$.
Of course we need the chain rule and the fact that 
$$ \frac{d^j}{ds^j}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s\left(\log x\right)^j e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\,dx,$$
plus $\frac{d}{dx}\Gamma(x+1) = \Gamma(x+1)\psi(x+1)$.

$$ \zeta'(0)=-\log\sqrt{2\pi},\qquad \zeta''(0)=\frac{\gamma^2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{\log^2(2\pi)}{2}+\gamma_1,\qquad \ldots $$
An alternative approach is to directly exploit the reflection formula for the $\zeta$ function, relating the derivatives at $s=0$ with the derivatives of $\eta(s)$ at $s=1$, which are given by conditionally convergent series of the form $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\left(\log n\right)^k}{n}$.

Comment: Many thanks, now I am going to study your details. Yours is a great and generous answer that I am reading. With the reference of the other answer is enough.